# Error 32603 Metamask to deploy an ERC20 on the EVM rollup

Tags: smart-contracts, smart-rollup, rollup, evm-rollup

Hi I am trying to deploy an ERC20 on the EVM rollup

I am copying this code for ERC20 and using the Remix IDE

When I use the "Remix VM (shanghai)", it works fine
[image]

However, when I switch to "Injected Provider - Metamask", I submit using the following, leave the gas to

- Gas limit: 1000000000
- Gas price (GWEI): 0.000021

[image]

And I end with the following error

```
creation of MyToken errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"data\":[{\"kind\":\"temporary\",\"id\":\"failure\",\"msg\":\"Invalid_argument(\\\"Temporary deactivated\\\")\"}]}}'","id":8493423935121633}
```

I have looked online for error 32603. People report errors due to

1. gas fees estimations -> I have tried crazy loads of different combinations and it did not work
2. nonce -> I have tried submitted with different nonces, created another account, cleared the transactions on metamask and it did not work :(

What should I do?

Comment: Following a twitter post

1. there was an issue handling operations over 4kbytes https://twitter.com/_lthms_/status/1692156827532689490?s=20

2. The stack exchange is not carefully looked at (unfortunately), devs need to join the dev slack 

I will followed up when I try deploying the contract again

Answer (score 0):

Good news it worked (managed to deploy the contract using Remix IDE)!

Probably the core devs fixed the issue